# How to make program keep ASCII values in erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have a function where I enter from the erlang shell:

```
huffman:table([$H,$E,$L,$L,$O]).
```

I want to keep the ASCII values like that, but mine are changed into integers in the output. How do I make the program not interpret them into integers?

Comment: The key point here is the list of integers returned by your `huffman:table/1` function does not contains only "printable characters". How do you want to display them ?

Comment: This is how I would like to get it back:[{1,5,{2,3,{$L,2},{$O,1}},3},{3,2,{$E,1},{$H,1}}] ( I have other integers in the list). Abit messy right now, but as you see I would like the ASCII values to remain like that after it went through my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$H` is just another way of writing the integer 72, there is no way to print it as `$H` built-in to Erlang. You'd have to write your own function to output the values this way.

In the example you show, it looks like you need to keep small integers as integers, while printing alphabetic values as letters.  Something like this might work:

```
maybe_char_to_string(N) when $A =< N, N =< $Z ->
    [$$, N];
maybe_char_to_string(N) ->
    integer_to_list(N).
```

This is what it outputs:

```
3> foo:maybe_char_to_string($H).
"$H"
4> foo:maybe_char_to_string(1).
"1"
```

Comment: Ah I see, that answers my question then, have to have a seperate function  if I want ASCII output. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Erlang doesn't distinguish characters and integers. In particular, Erlang string-literals like `"HELLO"` result in a list `[$H, $E, $L, $L, $O]`. The shell decides by a heuristic (basically checking that all integers are printable unicode characters) whether it outputs `[72, 69, 76, 76, 79]` or `"HELLO"`. Here's the output in my shell session:

```
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
1> [$H,$E,$L,$L,$O].
"HELLO"
2>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print something as string, use:

```
io:format("~s", [String]).
```